# SDL measuring text

Tags: c, sdl

I am working on an implementation of a text input in C using SDL so I need to get the length of the text so that I can place the cursor in the right position. any idea how to measure text ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TTF_SizeText](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_39.html) (Assuming you are using SDL_ttf)